1 n-variable inequality with strange constraints
let n>k are positive integers and n real number $a_1,...,a_n \in (k-1,k)$. consider positive real numbers $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ sastified with all $I\subset$ {1,2,...,n} and $\vert I\vert=k$
$\sum_{i \subset I}{a_i}\geq{\sum_{i \subset I}{x_i}}$
find maximum of $x_1x_2...x_n$
i'm not making much progress on this problem, nor do i have much direction. i see that we can change the condition $|I|=k$ to $|I|\geq k$ by taking the sets of I and adding the inequalities together, i think the answer to the problem is $a_1...a_n$ but still not sure, the problem is really confusing to me, please give your opinion, thanks a lot
